# Stored Procedure Parameter Like Check

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, wildcard, sql-like

I have a stored procedure that when ran shows a list of all the filenames in a table. I want it to be optional to pick the file name that you are looking for. Here's my code :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [schema].[getFileName] (
  @FileName NVARCHAR(500) = N'%' ) AS
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM table t
WHERE t.FileName like '%' + @FileName + '%'

END
GO
```

When I run this:

```
EXEC getFileName
```

I only get a single filename back instead of the several contained inside the table.

---

I just figured out that not all the rows in the table contain a filename (it's *NULL*) and this is why I don't get the expected results. I need to figure out how to work around this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean? Please explain

Comment: What is the issue with your code?

Comment: @GordonLinoff When I run EXEC getFileName with this code I only get a single filename, however, the table contains several different ones

Comment: @Justcode I only get back one filename instead of the several different ones that the table contains.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [schema].[getFileName] (
  @FileName NVARCHAR(500) = N'' ) AS
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM table t
WHERE t.FileName like '%' + @FileName + '%'

END
GO
```

Comment: Still only gives me back a single filename instead of all the different ones in the table, but thanks for your help.